# How can I change the background inside guides geometry on ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the background inside guides geometry (those in gray that are signaled by the red arrows)
[image]

```
 library(ggplot2)

    dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, p = 1:5, q = factor(1:5),
                      r = factor(1:5))
    p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, colour = p, size = q, shape = r)) + geom_point()

    p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, colour = p, size = q, shape = r)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "green"))
```